# How can I update a column with row_number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I udpate a column with `row_number` in SQL Server 2008 R2?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

DECLARE @count int 
DECLARE @maxcount int 
SET @count = 1

SET @maxcount = (SELECT count(*)
                 FROM   Applicant_Detail ad
                 WHERE  ad.identification_code = 1)
PRINT @maxcount

WHILE (@count<@maxcount)
BEGIN
    UPDATE ad
    SET    ad.NRIC_nbr = s.myRowNumber
    FROM   Applicant_Detail ad
    INNER JOIN   (
               SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NRIC_nbr ASC) AS myRowNumber
               FROM   Applicant_Detail ad
           )S
      ON   s.myRowNumber = @count
      SET @count = @count+1
END
```

This query takes a lot of time. I do not have any column in the `applicant_detail` table which has sequential data? I use the count logic but takes lot of time?

**What i want?**
Update the column of the table with sequential data like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...... max row of the table?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @count int = (select count(1) from Applicant_Detail)

;with cte as 
(select *, row_number() over (order by @count) rn
 from Applicant_Detail)

 update cte
 set NRIC_nbr = rn

 select * from Applicant_Detail
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MFNRK56617)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this problem

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
;WITH numbering AS 
( SELECT AD.NRIC_nbr,
         AD.application_number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AD.application_number) AS ROWNUMBER 
  FROM   Applicant_Detail ad WHERE AD.identification_code=1
)
UPDATE numbering 
SET NRIC_nbr=ROWNUMBER
```

Comment: Using a transaction is a best practice

Answer (score -1):

when you want to update the column with row_numebr. it is the perfect solution

WITH TEMP AS
  (
    SELECT id as rid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID] ASC) AS RN
    FROM ORG 
  )
 update ORG Set columnname1 ='200'+(select RN FROM TEMP where TEMP.rid=ORG.id)

Comment: This format is invalid and definitely needs some spare changes. Hope you change this and thanks in advance!

Comment: I am posting my direct query hope you u will understand.                                      WITH TEMP AS (
  select attributepropertyid as rid,value1,value2,modelvarientid from tbcompetitorattributevalues
  ) 
 --select * from TEMP
 update backdel Set value2 =(select value2 FROM TEMP where TEMP.rid=backdel.attributepropertyid and  TEMP.modelvarientid=backdel.modelvarientid
 ) where
  modelvarientid=2217 and modelreference=2009

Comment: You will need to format the code in stackoverflow, so the code is better readable.